# Slideshow on 2 images, css/javascript

Tags: html, css

i've been trying to make the slideshow with css or javascript but no luck, i need slideshow on 2 images on every 2 seconds.Below is my html code, i want my slideshow to be at events-img class.
Thanks in advance.

```
 <div class="second-section">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 events-img">
                <img src="img/apple-gs-os.png">
                <img src="img/f5.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 pen">
                <img src="img/pen.png">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 events-info">
                <div class="col-md-12 logo-wrap">
                    <img src="img/digitLogo.png" class="events-info-logo">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 events-info-text">
                    <p>
                    lorem ipsum
                  </p>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">More Info</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row square">
            <div class="col-md-12 squares">
                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum 
                </p>
            </div>
            <img src="img/123.png">
        </div>
    </div>


    var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("events-img");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      x[i].style.display = "none"; 
    }
    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > x.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: you have to add your attempt

Comment: http://prntscr.com/de6u9f

Something like this one.

Comment: you need to add what you tried so far ...and if you are using bootstrap you should look for "carousel"

Comment: @Chiller i tried carousel but no luck, i have no experience and still learning, i have updated my code, added my javascript.
Thanks in advance guys

Comment: you can fallow this tutorials it may help you start :https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/bootstrap-3-carousel-tutorial/  http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-carousel.php

Comment: @Chiller thank you very much

Comment: you are welcome mate